# Spring Boot OAuth CORS Problem - Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status

Tags: java, spring-boot, cors

I have problems integrating the CORS filter into my spring boot (2.3) OAuth application. I read the posts of a lot of other people with the same problem but could not find a solution for mine.
When accessing my application via Postman I do not have any issues getting the authentication key. However, when using a HTML file from my local system where I use an ajax query (using jQuery) to access the application I am getting the follwing error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at '**my sercice**' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

My code looks like this:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsUtils;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

import de.mtc.procon.authserver.provider.CustomAuthenticationProvider;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }


//  @Bean
//  public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
//      return new MyCorsFilter(getMyCorsConfigurationSource());
//  }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("---------------------- Configure authentication server -----------------------");
        http.cors().and().authorizeRequests().requestMatchers(CorsUtils::isPreFlightRequest).permitAll().antMatchers("/**").authenticated().and().httpBasic().and().csrf().disable().exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint());
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Qualifier
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        System.out.println("Generating cors configuration source...");
        return getMyCorsConfigurationSource();
    }

    private CorsConfigurationSource getMyCorsConfigurationSource() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", getMyCorsConfiguration());
        return source;
    }

    private CorsConfiguration getMyCorsConfiguration() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("authorization", "content-type", "x-auth-token"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setMaxAge(Duration.ofDays(1));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("x-auth-token"));
        return configuration;
    }
}
```

Could I be using classes from wrong packages? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Your title mentions OAuth, but I can't see any resource-server configuration. Are you trying to setup OAuth authentication (withe Beaarer token) or username/password authentication (like the `setAllowCredentials(true)` could indicate)?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to setup OAuth with Bearer tokens. The authentication server generates the JWT token based on provided username and password and returns it. The token is used to access the resource server which is an independant application (not a spring boot application). When accessing the resource server, I do not have any issues with CORS or better I fixed those. I only habe problems when quering the token from the authentication server.
I am not very experienced with spring boot, so if I have made a mistake in the configuration, it is probably due to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.

What I was missing was the annotation

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
```

However, when I added it to my class WebSecurityConfiguration, I got the error

> InsufficientAuthenticationException: There is no client authentication.

In the end I removed the corsConfigurationSource Bean and the cors() method from the HttpSecurity and added a CorsFilter class. To this new class I added the @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE) annotation. Additionally, I added addFilterBefore to the HttpSecurity.

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        return new CorsFilter();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(corsFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class).csrf().disable().exceptionHandling().and()    .authorizeRequests().requestMatchers(CorsUtils::isPreFlightRequest).permitAll().antMatchers("/**").authenticated().and().httpBasic()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(new CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint());
    }

    
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    private class CorsFilter implements Filter //javax.servlet.Filter 
    {

        @Override
        public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

        }

        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type,Authorization");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400");
            if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest).getMethod())) {
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            } else {
                filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, response);
            }
            
        }

        @Override
        public void destroy() {

        }
    }
}
```